# Interop.Excel 0x800A03EC - Out of memory error code 7

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to cycle through a excel workbook and copy paste values over the top
of each sheet within that workbook. But I am running into a memory issue on line:
ws.select(true), when going to the next sheet.

Errors encountered:

Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC: 
and when I go to close out of the workbook at this point excel throws: 
Out of memory (Error 7)

Additional information:

> File size 3mb, 20 tabs and lots of database formulae reading from olap database TM1.
>   Microsoft office 2007

The code I am running is below. Is there a more efficient way of running it that may prevent the Out of Memory Error OR is this something different??

Any help would be much appreciated!

#

```
    public bool wbCopyValueOnly(string workBook) 
    { 

    Workbook wb = excel.ActiveWorkbook;
    Worksheet ws;
    Range rng;

    int WS_Count = wb.Sheets.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < WS_Count; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            ws = wb.Sheets[i + 1];
            ws.Activate();
            ws.Select(true);
            //ws.Select(Type.Missing);
            //ws.Cells.Select();
            ws.UsedRange.Select();

            //ws.Cells.Copy();
            ws.UsedRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
            ws.UsedRange.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
            // select of range to get around memory issue
            excel.Application.CutCopyMode = (Excel.XlCutCopyMode)0;
            //rng = ws.get_Range("A1");
            //rng.Select();
            NAR(ws);

        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException err)
        {

            cLogging.write(LogLevel.Error, err.Message);
            Debug.Print(err.Message);
            return false;
        }


    }
    NAR(wb);
    return true;

    }


    private void NAR(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            while (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o) > 0) ;
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            o = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you try with office 2003 and 2010? As well as from another pc?

Answer (score 1):

I have a program that copies from up to 100 tabs back to the first summary page and I found that using .Copy() caused several problems. Especially if your program runs for a length of time; the current user cannot use the copy-paste function without strange results.  I recommend using variables to store what you need and then write to the intended range.  Recording Macros is invaluable if you need to change the format of the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
ws.Activate();
ws.Select(true);
ws.UsedRange.Select();
```

I think these code isn't necessary.

You can record a Marco to learn how to modify your code.

Comment: Worth a try on a different environment, bonCodigo. Problem is the solution needs to be deployed on a 2007 environment.... applogies if my code above has a little duplication, it was me attempting a number of different ways to get it to work....